# Windows 8 app modification results in "This app can't open"

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app

I was pretty sick of the Windows 8 app Messenger purple color, so I decided to make some basic modifications to the app's CSS to change it. Unfortunately, after initially opening the app it exited almost immediately with the vague message "This app can't open", prompting me to reinstall it. Is there a way I can bypass this security behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the application then the signature is no longer valid, so it won't load. Under Windows 8 there isn't a way to disable this signature verification.

You're stuck on this one I'm afraid until Windows 8 is properly jailbroken.

Comment: One solution is to use a different Messenger application that allows for the configuration of the cosmetic look of the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain that the answer is a very unfortunate no. I tried to do the same thing and now the Store app is "repairing" my Messenger install.